# Excel VBA Search columns of long text string and replace characters within it

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked at all the examples and answers on this site and came up with this little program below. However, instead of replacing only the two lines that contains "802722AA", it replaces everything else that does NOT contain the string as well. I am out of ideas as to why this happens. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceAGF()

Dim Loc As Range
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheets(2).UsedRange
    Range("A1").Select
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="802722AA")
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Do
                Loc.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Replace What:="AGF", Replacement:="AGN", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
                RowNum = Loc.Row
                Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
            Loop While Loc.Row > RowNum
        End If
    End With
    Set Loc = Nothing
```

My data looks like this, I'm just redacting it because it's a 400+ line list.

```
802722AA SANTA ROSA LEASING LLC2    AGF
59511VAA MICRON SEMICONDUCTOR       AGF
973204AA WINDERMERE AVIATION LLC    AGY
92242VAB VCK LEASE SA               AGF
68839PAB OSPREY AIRCRAFT LEASING    AGF
79977TAC SANDALWOOD 2013 LLC        AGN
02154QAA ALTITUDE INVEST 16 LLC     AGF
802722AA SANTA ROSA LEASING LLC     AGF
45170$88 ILLINOIS FACILITIES FUND   ACM
```

Note that this is a text file all dumped into column A in Excel. I cannot text to column it and I cannot do any fancy formulas whatsoever because it feeds to a proprietary program that will refuse the input. Note that there are a few AGF there and I only want it changed to AGN if it contains the text 802722AA.

Comment: Your vba macro above will not do what you want. Replaces all AGF with AGN. I will try to fix it in the answer

Comment: Yeah, That is exactly my predicament at this point -- it replaces everything, including the ones i don't want replaced. I mean the logic is sound as it should search for the next match and replace. I just don't get why it's replacing lines that don't have a match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data in column "A" with header in row 1, you can use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("MySheetName")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp))
            .Autofilter field:=1, Criteria1:="802722*"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then . Replace "AGF", "AGN"
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't quite work as I am getting errors. However, I think the logic behind your code is to do a filter on each search criteria and then do a replace all on the filtered results. I think this will only be faster than brute force line by line search / replace if there are a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Which errors? Be sure to 1) change "MySheetName" to your actual worksheet name 2) have headers in cell A1 and data from A2 downwards

Comment: Error 1004 on .AutoFilter firld:=1, Criteria1:="802722*" -- Application / Object not defined.

Comment: Expect end of statement on .Replace "AGF" "AGN"

Comment: Worked! Definitely a little faster than my current brute force method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, and this may not be all that efficient, I think I'd make use of the `split` function like this

```
finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row 'get the last row of column A
for i=2 to finalRow 
    parts = split(cells(i,1), " ") 'make an array out of the parts separated by spaces
    newString = ""
    if parts(0) = "802722AA" and parts(ubound(parts))="AGF" then 
       for j=lbound(parts) to ubound(parts) - 1 'get all but the last part
           newString = newString & " " & parts(j) 'make a new string of all but the last part
       next j
       newString = newString & " AGN" 'at the end, replace the AGF with AGN
    end if
    cells(i,1)=newString 'replace contents of cell with our newly constructed string
next i
```

Comment: I did something similar to yours by matching the first 8 character of the line with the find criteria and just loop through it line by line with an IF statement. It works but true that not the most efficient way of doing it. Thanks!